# .Net Core Webapi Get Base Address URL on Automapper profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, webapi

I'm relatively new to the auto mapper and I have a scenario that I want to map the member of my DTO class called "AttachmentUrl" this attachment URl is a string that contains a combination of the base URL of API and parameter as GUID Id. **`$"{BaseUrl}notes/download/{sc.Id}"`**. Kindly find the profile mapper code given below.

```
 public NoteProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<NoteDto, Note>().ReverseMap().ForMember(a => a.AttachmentUrl,
                ac=>ac.MapFrom( sc => $"{BaseUrl}notes/download/{sc.Id}")) ;

        }

public class NoteDto
    {
        public Guid NoteId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }    

        //This has to be mapped using auto mapper
        public string AttachmentUrl { get; set; }
        
    }

public class Note 
    {
        public Guid NoteId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }   
        public byte[] Content { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        

    }
```

How do I get the web API base URL on the auto mapper profile? (**{BaseUrl}**)

Comment: add Your datatypes please, it is confusing what you are trying to do when we cannot see what you're trying to match up

Comment: @T.Nielsen I have updated the question with datatypes as you requested

Comment: My guess will be to add the `BaseUrl` has a parameter in your appsettings.json and inject the `IConfiguration` inside your `NoteProfile(IConfiguration configuration)` like that you can retrieve the BaseUrl inside your profile.

Comment: thanks @Anurag, so your BaseUrl exist only going from the dto to the model and is then thrown away and then how do you get it back is the problem, right?
So can that baseUrl be more urls than one?